# Retrieving Query String Parameters and JSON body from wrapped HTTP request (using ServletRequestWrapper)

Tags: java, servlets, wrapper, servlet-filters

Sending both query string and JSON body in HTTP Post request to a server is possible this is what I have understood already. To do this we need to Override the getReader and getInputstream methods of HttpServletRequestWrapper class. I have done this as studied in this [link](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-create-duplicate-object-of-httpServletRequest-object). Saw similar answers in Stack Overflow as well.

So right now I have a login action where there is no body, just the query string params coming in post. While I try to read them it gives me null as output for getParameter(). In my wrapper I print the body that is captured and it shows proper the correct data received from client machine.

Trivial methods of reading the query String (`getParameter()`) and JSON body (gson.fromJson) that are used while reading from unWrapped HttpRequest can be used on the wrapped HTTP Request as well? What am I missing here?

POST method of servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("from doPost");

    RequestWrapper wrappedrequest = new RequestWrapper(request);

    request = wrappedrequest;

    String action= request.getParameter("action");

    if(action.equals("update")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Order cart = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), Order.class);
            CartDao dao= new CartDao(cart);

            dao.addData();

        }else if(action.equals("login")) {
            loginDao ld = new loginDao(request);
            int roleId = ld.authenticate();

            if(roleId!=-1) {

                System.out.println("Role ID Got is "+ roleId);
                HttpSession session = ld.loadSession(roleId);
                System.out.println("Init page for logging in user is = "+ session.getAttribute("initPage").toString());
                CartDao dao= new CartDao();
                JsonArray responseJson=  dao.getOrderList();

                request.setAttribute("ResponseJson", responseJson);

                RequestDispatcher rq = request.getRequestDispatcher(session.getAttribute("initPage").toString());
                rq.forward(request, response);


            }else {
                request.setAttribute("errmsg", "Invalid username/password");
                RequestDispatcher rq = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                rq.forward(request, response);
            }

        }else {

            System.out.println("No Action");
        }

}
```

RequestWrapper

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private String _body;

public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    _body = "";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader();           
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        _body += line; //when i print this it shows proper data got from client machine

    }
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(_body.getBytes());
    return new ServletInputStream() {
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked this myself. All i had to do was to read the query string and save it in a map and return the value by taking the key in getParameter overridden method. and the body is saved by reading the input stream and is returned when the overridden  getReader is called. and this can be called any number of times. :) although this works, would be great if someone could explain in detail saying why it works.

the Star code that does the magic is shown below,

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {



private String _body;
private String _queryString;

public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    _body = "";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader();           
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        _body += line;
    }

     _queryString = request.getQueryString();

     System.out.println(_body + _queryString);
}
}
```